# error 1452: Foreign Key error

Tags: mysql-error-1452

I am new to mysql and I am trying create a gradebook db to keep track of grades for a certain class. I am using Mysql workbench and here is my code:

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;

SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `nj1368843` ;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;

USE `nj1368843` ;

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Users`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Users` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Users` (

`idUsers` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`UserName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

`pw` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`idUsers`, `UserName`, `pw`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `nj1368843`.`Users` (`UserName`, `pw`) VALUES ('njack2', '123');

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Teachers`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Teachers` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Teachers` (

`idTeachers` INT NOT NULL ,

`Lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Users_idUsers` INT NOT NULL ,

`Users_pw` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`idTeachers`) ,

INDEX `fk_Teachers_Users1` (`Users_idUsers` ASC, `Users_pw` ASC) ,

CONSTRAINT `fk_Teachers_Users1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Users_idUsers` , `Users_pw` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Users` (`idUsers` , `UserName` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `nj1368843`.`Teachers` (`idTeachers`, `Lname`, `Fname`, `Users_idUsers`, `Users_pw`) VALUES (105, 'Stacey', 'Sheila', '1', '123');

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Schedule`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Schedule` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Schedule` (

`course_id` INT NOT NULL ,

`Semester` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Year` YEAR NULL ,

`Teachers_idTeachers` INT NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`) ,

INDEX `fk_Grades_Teachers1` (`Teachers_idTeachers` ASC) ,

CONSTRAINT `fk_Grades_Teachers1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Teachers_idTeachers` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Teachers` (`idTeachers` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB;

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Assignments`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Assignments` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Assignments` (

`idAssignments` INT NOT NULL ,

`Assignment 1` INT NULL ,

`AVG_Grade` INT(11) NULL ,

`Schedule_course_id` INT NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`idAssignments`) ,

INDEX `fk_Assignments_Schedule1` (`Schedule_course_id` ASC) ,

CONSTRAINT `fk_Assignments_Schedule1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Schedule_course_id` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Schedule` (`course_id` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB;

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Student`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Student` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Student` (

`idStudent` INT NOT NULL ,

`lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Schedule_course_id` INT NOT NULL ,

`Users_idUsers` INT NOT NULL ,

`Users_pw` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

`Assignments_idAssignments` INT NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`idStudent`) ,

INDEX `fk_Student_Schedule1` (`Schedule_course_id` ASC) ,

INDEX `fk_Student_Users1` (`Users_idUsers` ASC, `Users_pw` ASC) ,

INDEX `fk_Student_Assignments1` (`Assignments_idAssignments` ASC) ,

CONSTRAINT `fk_Student_Schedule1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Schedule_course_id` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Schedule` (`course_id` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

CONSTRAINT `fk_Student_Users1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Users_idUsers` , `Users_pw` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Users` (`idUsers` , `UserName` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

CONSTRAINT `fk_Student_Assignments1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Assignments_idAssignments` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Assignments` (`idAssignments` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB;

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Classes`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Classes` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Classes` (

`cid` INT NOT NULL ,

`Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Schedule_course_id` INT NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`cid`) ,

INDEX `fk_Classes_Schedule1` (`Schedule_course_id` ASC) ,

CONSTRAINT `fk_Classes_Schedule1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Schedule_course_id` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Schedule` (`course_id` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB;

---

-- Table `nj1368843`.`Teachers`

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Teachers` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nj1368843`.`Teachers` (

`idTeachers` INT NOT NULL ,

`Lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

`Users_idUsers` INT NOT NULL ,

`Users_pw` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`idTeachers`) ,

INDEX `fk_Teachers_Users1` (`Users_idUsers` ASC, `Users_pw` ASC) ,

CONSTRAINT `fk_Teachers_Users1`

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Users_idUsers` , `Users_pw` )

REFERENCES `nj1368843`.`Users` (`idUsers` , `UserName` )

ON DELETE NO ACTION

ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;

SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

I generated this out of an erd diagram and I can't insert any information in the database because I get:

ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nj1368843`.`Teachers`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Teachers_Users1` FOREIGN KEY (`Users_idUsers`, `Users_pw`) REFERENCES `Users` (`idUsers`, `UserName`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

SQL Statement:

INSERT INTO `nj1368843`.`Teachers` (`idTeachers`, `Lname`, `Fname`, `Users_idUsers`, `Users_pw`) VALUES (105, 'Stacey', 'Sheila', 1, '123')

I tried everyone's ideas and looked over the code a million times and still can't find the problem. I can't insert into none of the tables for this db.help.